# Query for mongoRepository list

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I have a MongoDB collection with documents with the following fields:

- date (Date obj)
- offerType (str)

I want to write a method with MongoRepository **to find all the documents that has date in a range of dates and offerType contains one of the string provided in a list**.

---

### Example

Documents:

1. date: 10-04-2019, offerType: offer1
2. date: 11-04-2019, offerType: offer3
3. date: 15-04-2019, offerType: offer2
4. date: 15-04-2019, offerType: offer1

I want:

- dates between 9-04-2019 and 12-04-2019
- following offers: offer1, offer3

In the previous example I would obtain documents 1 and 2.

---

### My code

I use MongoRepository and a custom Object which contains the fields I require:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;     
public interface ReportVocalOrderRepository extends MongoRepository<ReportVocalOrder, String> {

    List<ReportVocalOrder> findByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate, Pageable pageable);

    List<ReportVocalOrder> findByDateBetweenAndOfferTypeContaining(Date startDate, Date endDate, List<String> offers, Pageable pageable);


}
```

Here is the document class:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = Constants.Mongo.Collections.VOCAL_ORDER_REPORT)
@ApiModel
public class ReportVocalOrder {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Date date;
private String offerType;
public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
public String getOfferType() {
        return offerType;
    }

    public void setOfferType(String offerType) {
        this.offerType = offerType;
    }
}
```

The first method of the MongoRepository works fine; the second one instead returns an empty list.
The problem is **to query the mongoRepository to search a field that can contain one of the values of the list passed as an argument**.

What's wrong with this implementation? There's a better way to implement this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought. I post an answer for whom is interested:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;     
public interface ReportVocalOrderRepository extends MongoRepository<ReportVocalOrder, String> {

    List<ReportVocalOrder> findByDateBetweenAndOfferTypeIn(Date startDate, Date endDate, List<String> offers, Pageable pageable);


}
```

So the point is to use the keyword `In`.

Answer (score 0):

We have another option to using Query

```
@Query(value = "{ 'groupId' :  ?0 , 'user.$id' : {$in: ?1} }", delete = true)
    List<GroupUser> deleteUserInGroup(String groupId, List<ObjectId> userId);
```

You can try it.